# Can markdown display code in multiple programming languages and switch between them using a tabs component?

Tags: markdown

In leetcode's markdown version, I can display code in multiple programming languages and switch between them using a tabs component?
Now i want to write notes in local markdown file(typora or obsidian).
Can I get the same result like the same result like leetcode.
[image: leetcode markdown multiple code block]

Comment: I see open feature requests for this for [GitHub Markup](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/435) and [CommonMark Markdown](https://github.com/github/cmark-gfm/issues/196). Both are effectively dead.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:
https://leetcode.com/discuss/general-discussion/1560831/markdown-reference-for-leetcode-formatting-cheatsheet

Basically we go to Playground Tab in Leetcode: https://leetcode.com/playground/

We basically get a sharing link here, which can be then used to embed our code to the answers we post.

```
<iframe src="https://leetcode.com/playground/GKja4qAy/shared" frameBorder="0" width="400" height="300"></iframe>
```

Comment: But, is there any way to do this in pure markdown? Seems silly to embed leetcode into all my `README.md` files.